# eigenvalue problem at differential-equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

It's an eigenvalue problem.

$$y"+ y' + \lambda y = 0$$

$x$ between $0$ and $1$

$$y(0) = y(1) = 0$$

1. How can I write the problem in Sturm-Liouville form?
2. How can I find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions?

Can you please tell me how?

Comment: I think you are overdoing it. Do you know how to solve a second order differential equation with constant coefficients? If so, then just do it for this one (you will get solutions in terms of $\lambda$). Then match with your boundary conditions, and you might be able to solve for $\lambda$.

Comment: @mickep not necessarily. It might be a homework problem where it's specifically asked to reduce it to the SL problem and solve it using SL theory.

Answer (score 1):

### Hint (Reducing to SL problem)

SL theory is about solving the eigenvalue problem
$$
(p y')' + qy + \lambda wy = 0
$$
or alternatively
$$
py'' + p'y' + qy + \lambda w y = 0 \tag 1
$$
with some boundary conditions.

In your case you have 
$$
y'' + y' + \lambda y = 0
$$
You can use good old integrating factor technique
$$
M y'' + M y' + M \lambda y = 0
$$
To match it with the form $(1)$, you need to require
$$
M' = M \implies M = e^x
$$
So your ODE becomes
$$
e^x y'' + e^x y' + \lambda e^x y = 0 \implies \left( e^x y'\right )' + \lambda e^x y = 0
$$
which is a SL problem with
$$
p = e^x,\ q = 0,\ w = e^x
$$

I leave part 2 of your question to you :)